# another regex...one of desired results is multiline created by captured groups

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to parse following:

```
echo -e 
'2011-10-24,ASDF.pdf.Upf Ge.XXX,00:00:04.160,-130509,"EC={Set:[{Tr:1319414404138 GlobCheck.123456},{Tr:1319414404138 GlobCheck.123333},{Tr:1319414404140 GlobCheck.123334}]}",00:00:04.147,-265018.1,-130509'
```

So far I came to this code:

```
sed 's/,[.]*{.*\(Glob.*\)},/,\1,/g'
```

I've also tried with looping:

```
sed -e :aloop -e 's/,[.]*{.*\(Glob.*\)},/,\1,/g;/,/N;//aloop'
```

And got:

```
2011-10-24,ASDF.pdf.Upf Ge.XXX,00:00:04.160,-130509,EC={Set:[{Tr:1319414404138 GlobCheck.123456},GlobCheck.123333,{Tr:1319414404140 GlobCheck.123334}]}",00:00:04.147,-265018.1,-130509
```

What I'm expecting is:

```
2011-10-24,ASDF.pdf.Upf Ge.XXX,00:00:04.160,-130509,GlobCheck.123456,GlobCheck.123333,GlobCheck.123334,00:00:04.147,-265018.1,-130509
```

Ideally resulting in multiple rows:

```
2011-10-24,ASDF.pdf.Upf Ge.XXX,00:00:04.160,-130509,GlobCheck.123456,00:00:04.147,-265018.1,-130509
2011-10-24,ASDF.pdf.Upf Ge.XXX,00:00:04.160,-130509,GlobCheck.123333,00:00:04.147,-265018.1,-130509
2011-10-24,ASDF.pdf.Upf Ge.XXX,00:00:04.160,-130509,GlobCheck.123334,00:00:04.147,-265018.1,-130509
```

Comment: have you forgotten the starting `"` ?  there is only one `"` in your input string. or it is just like that?

Comment: input corrected, but some records might not have quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the awk solution below:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=5;i<=NF-3;i++) a[i]=gensub(/.*(GlobCheck\.[0-9]*).*/,"\\1","g",$i);
for(x in a) printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,a[x],$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF
}' yourFile
```

test with your input:

```
kent$  echo -e '2011-10-24,ASDF.pdf.Upf Ge.XXX,00:00:04.160,-130509,"EC={Set:[{Tr:1319414404138 GlobCheck.123456},{Tr:1319414404138 GlobCheck.123333},{Tr:1319414404140 GlobCheck.123334}]}",00:00:04.147,-265018.1,-130509'|\
awk -F, '{for(i=5;i<=NF-3;i++) a[i]=gensub(/.*(GlobCheck\.[0-9]*).*/,"\\1","g",$i);
for(x in a) printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,a[x],$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF
}'

output:

2011-10-24,ASDF.pdf.Upf Ge.XXX,00:00:04.160,-130509,GlobCheck.123456,00:00:04.147,-265018.1,-130509
2011-10-24,ASDF.pdf.Upf Ge.XXX,00:00:04.160,-130509,GlobCheck.123333,00:00:04.147,-265018.1,-130509
2011-10-24,ASDF.pdf.Upf Ge.XXX,00:00:04.160,-130509,GlobCheck.123334,00:00:04.147,-265018.1,-130509
```

Comment: There was small bug, i've corrected, you should wrap $NF-2 with brackets => $(NF-2)

Answer (score 0):

This sed solution might work:

```
sed -r 's/,/,!!!@@@/4;:a;s/@@@[^G]*(G[^}]*)}(\]\}")?,/\1,@@@/;ta;G;:b;s/^((.*)!!!)([^,]*,)(([^,]*,)*)(@@@(.*)\n.*)/\1\4\6!!!\2\3\7/;tb;s/.*\n!!!//;s/!!!/\n/g' input_file
```

Its not very elegant and I'm sure it can be refactored into a shorter solution but it's late and it seems  to work.